# asp.net mvc3, why do we need service layer when we use repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern, service-layer

I was watching "storefront starter kit", its using repository pattern with service layer.  In the video, he didnt really explain why he's using service layer.  Seems like those are just extra.

what are pros and cons using service layer?

Comment: Try to read this book first. It will help you to understand why to bring in complexity in design and separate concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most asp.net mvc apps it is perfectly reasonable and preferable for your controllers to directly address the repository (via an interface). I would only add a service layer when you need to, for example when other apps are interfacing with your application. In my opinion you should avoid unnecessary abstraction layers.

Answer (score 6):

Repository is your Data Layer ... it's responsibility is to fetch and save data.

The Service Layer is your Business Layer ... it's responsibility is to hold all your business logic.

Comment: All my MVC3 sites have a Service layer and a repository.  My MVC3 site never accesses the repository directly, but rather thru the service layer. My Service layer transforms data from the repository into view model and/or domain objects and contains all the business logic for my application. My mvc3 site then only manages displaying and gathering data. The service layer does all the heavy lifting.  So, my site never knows or cares where the data is coming from or going to.  This may not work for you, but it has worked for me and is just an example.